# calling python method name from name

Tags: python

What is the difference when calling python methods from names and from class.

Take for example the time API.

```
import time
time.strptime("some params")
```

However,

When i tried to create a python file (`xyz.py)`

```
xyz.py 
def test():
    print 1
```

And i tried the following:

```
import abc 
abc.test() --- > module has no attribute test
```

How do i achieve what the time API did

EDIT:

Saved the filename as xyz instead of abc and the error was resolved.

Comment: There is already an `abc` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html How are the classes set up? Perhaps you're importing the standard `abc` module?

Comment: Python's `abc` module provides Abstract Base Classes.  Choose a different name for your module.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Hi, Maybe i should rephrase my question properly

Comment: Maybe you should share the actual code that's causing this instead.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I guess it was due to naming the file as abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When python searches for a module to import, it [first](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) uses `sys.modules` or the built-in modules:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found ...

Since there is already an [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) you're importing the wrong module.

Change the name of your module.